# Force Popen processes to execute in certain order in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, popen

There's  5 processes created and run by subprocess.Popen(someexternalCommand). It's important for the commands to be started sequentially, i.g. the second process must not start until the first has started and running. 
The following code was used :

```
proc1 = TrafficGenUtils.Popen(someexternalCommand)
time.sleep(10)
proc2 = TrafficGenUtils.Popen(someexternalCommand)
time.sleep(10)
...
```

the order of execution was maintained when the number of processes was 3, but with 5 it's almost never maintained and increasing sleep to even 60 seconds doesn't help. 
How to force the execution of Popen processes to be sequential.
Is the reason my code doesn't work linked to the fact that Popen relies on OS to create the processes but OS starts them whenever it pleases? I'm using Windows 8 and python 2.7

Comment: How do *you* know when a process "has started and running"? Then you'll need to write code to teach your program to look for the same thing(s). If you control the code for the processes you're starting, this can be much easier (e.g., a process could create a new file when it's ready, and your main program could wait for that new file to appear).  BTW, `sleep()` is almost never an adequate approach for solving inter-process (or even inter-thread) communication problems.

Comment: thanks. but i'm not in control of the processes the main program is starting. the processes are exe files.

Comment: So I ask again:  how do *you* know when a process "has started and is running?".  There's no magic here.  You know or you don't know.  If you don't know, the problem is unsolvable.  If you do know, than you have to teach your program how to know too.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I think i will check if child processes are in the list of running processes.

Comment: I hope that's good enough! Can't guess. It's possible for the OS to start a process (at which point it will appear in the list of running processes), but then not give it enough time to (for example) finish initializing before the OS gives the CPU(s) to other processes. That's why this can be very much easier if you control the processes' code. You may even need to wait for a child process to accumulate "enough" CPU time to guess that it's probably ready to do something useful. No magic here :-(

Answer (score 1):

`Popen` starts a new process and therefore from that moment on it's up to the OS to schedule its run time. Not only can you not assume one process will run before another, but you can't even assume your parent process will yield execution to the child, at its actually likely not to.

In order to create sequenced execution you can use `proc1.wait()` to stop the parent process until the child process finishes its execution. This way you can guarantee that the processes will run in order, since the parent process will not go on until the child process ends and thus will not spawn the other children.

Read more in the [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects).

Comment: Thanks. However, my problem is that i don't want the first child process to end  and then the second to start, but the first to start, the second to start and so on. The child processes will run in the background until i call proc.terminate on them.